# Replace null values from a select command in jq with the value of another field

Tags: json, jq, jtc

Goal is to search for null values of part_description and insert in part field value.

```
[
  {
    "part": "brake-01982",
    "part_description": null,
  }
]
```

Expected Output

```
[
  {
    "part": "brake-01982",
    "part_description": "brake-01982",
  }
]
```

Command:
jq '(.[] | select(.part_description==null).part_description) |= .part'

Results in no change

What does work is if I try to insert a string value. The double quoted string results in what I would expect. Demo below. How do I pass another fields value into this command vs a quoted string?

Command: jq '(.[] | select(.part_description==null).part_description) |= "test"'

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XkYATvJona)

Output

```
[
  {
    "part": "brake-01982",
    "part_description": "test"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative operator `//` retains the first value, unless it is `null`, `false`, or `empty` (i.e. missing), in which case it takes on the second. Combined with the update operator `|=`, this can be contracted to `//=`.

```sh
jq '.[] |= (.part_description //= .part)'
```

```json
[
  {
    "part": "brake-01982",
    "part_description": "brake-01982"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vO_AAh9rqA)

---

Edit: To strictly update only in the case of `null`, i.e. to keep a value of `false`, and to not create the field if it's missing, the filter needs to check explicity for `null`:

```sh
jq '.[] |= ((select(has("part_description")).part_description | select(. == null)) = .part)'
```

```json
[
  {
    "part": "brake-01982",
    "part_description": "brake-01982"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/T66tOtyWp1)

Comment: Interesting. Never seen this approach. Thank you. That worked great.

Answer (score 0):

> Goal is to search for null values of part_description ....

If this is indeed the goal, then you would need to test for `null` rather than relying on `//` or `//=`.  So you could write:

```
map( if has("part_description") and .part_description == null
     then .part_description = .part else . end )
```